# Python - Extracting data from text to use

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, replace

probably a basic question to most.
Though I am looking at getting some specific values that would follow certain words within a mass amount of text like so - (https://character-service.dndbeyond.com/character/v5/character/00000001)

In this instance if I wanted to take the value after baseHitPoints and also the value after removedHitPoints how would I go about this in the simplest way? The aim is to take these values and any others, even potentially text after a certain word, and store them as strings/integers to use in calculations.

I am also using BeautifulSoup to get this information if that effects anything in your answers.

Thanks in advance!

Tried a few different approaches.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Post the code you've tried and explain clearly where you are stuck (showing your current and desired results). Also, include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Posts on Stack Overflow need to be self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

### Learning JSON document structure

First of all, you don't actually need to use BeautifulSoup here. The URL is targeting to JSON document, which is quite easy to navigate and get values from if you know the structure of JSON document.

1. To examine the structure of JSON document I can recommend using browser extensions for prettifying JSON, like [JSON lite](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/json-lite/) for Opera. But this is not best approach if JSON document is so large, your browser will be struggling render so much text, and extension will be struggling trying to format the JSON document. If document is large - use second approach.
2. You can download JSON document, and use Text Editors with plugins for JSON prettifying (like powerful `Notepad++`, plugin `JSFormat`).
3. Also, you can examine the structure of JSON document dirrectly in python using library for pretty print output called [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) (this is also not the best option with large documents).

```
import pprint

json = {"data": {"actions": {"items": [1, 2, 3], "colors": ['red', 'green', 'blue'], "items1": [1, 2, 3], "items2": {"numbers": [1, 2, 3], "characters": ['a', 'b', 'c']}}, "some_other_data": ['one', 'two', 'three']}, "new_data": [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]}

pprint.pprint(json)
```

Outputs same structure but more structured, and you can easily check how to retrieve certain value from JSON:

```
{'data': {'actions': {'colors': ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
                      'items': [1, 2, 3],
                      'items1': [1, 2, 3],
                      'items2': {'characters': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                                 'numbers': [1, 2, 3]}},
          'some_other_data': ['one', 'two', 'three']},
 'new_data': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]}
```

### Retrieving data from your URL

As we can see from the JSON document in your URL, JSON-path to `baseHitPoints` is: `data -> baseHitPoints`. JSON-path to `removedHitPoints` is: `data -> removedHitPoints`.

Knowing that, we can now easily retrieve those values using library `requests`:

```
import requests

URL = "https://character-service.dndbeyond.com/character/v5/character/00000001"

req = requests.get(URL)
json_data = req.json()

baseHitPoints = json_data['data']['baseHitPoints']
removedHitPoints = json_data['data']['removedHitPoints']

print(f"{baseHitPoints = }\n{removedHitPoints = }")
```

Output:

```
baseHitPoints = 8
removedHitPoints = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is JSON, not really a standard string. Because that's JSON you can get the data out of there easily by doing something like this:

```
import json
myData = json.load(myJSON) #myJSON would be the contents of that link(https://character-service.dndbeyond.com/character/v5/character/00000001) you provided


baseHitPoints = myData["data"]["baseHitPoints"]
removedHitPoints = myData["data"]["removedHitPoints"]
```

The values of those variables in my example using your JSON:

- baseHitPoints = 8
- baseHitPoints = 2

To make your life a little easier going forward I'd look for a tutorial for how to parse through JSON.